# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Update Attributes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, attributes

I have trying to allow a user to edit their account (simple enough, eh?)

Here is my Update Method:

```
  def update
    @user = current_user
    # @user.attributes = {'mail_chimp_newsletters' => []}.merge(params[:user])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to edit_account_path, :notice => 'Account has been updated!'
    else
      redirect_to edit_account_path, :flash => { :alert => "Account could not be updated. Please try again" }
    end
  end
```

Route:

```
match 'account/edit' => 'settings#edit', :as => 'edit_account', :via => :get
match 'accounts' => 'settings#update', :as => 'accounts', :via => :put
```

HTML Form:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => accounts_url, :method => :put, :html => { :id => "personal-info-form", :class => "hide" } do |f| %>
```

When the form is submitted, this is dump in the `console`:

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 43008 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (36.1ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`username` = BINARY 'test@test.com' AND `users`.`id` != 43008) LIMIT 1
  User Exists (33.4ms)  SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`email` = BINARY 'test@test.com' AND `users`.`id` != 43008) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
```

I'm not sure why this is not working... anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Change `update_attributes` to `update_attributes!` so we can see the error, that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you have a User model and an authentication system like Devise or AuthLogic.  When those are added to User you now need to explicitly declare attributes as read and write able as in

```
# User model (models/user.rb)
attr_accessor :email, last_name, first_name # etc.
```

Comment: ha, funny you should mention that... I just ran a debugger on the save and its because of the password being sent in as blank

Comment: Thanks for the help, michael, it was one of those things that I overlooked lol